# Which User Editted or Created The Data Column (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgresql database with postgis extension. We are editing and creating the data with 8-10 different users. I need to know (record) which user created which data, with a column.

Comment: Postgres does not store this information. You will need to do that inside your application that "edits" the data

Comment: We are editing the data with QGIS, so I need to do that via QGIS... Now things get harder.

Comment: Or easier. Essentially, you're asking for a way to audit QGIS changes. If you google for `qgis audit` you'll find some plugins that do that. Some of them use an [audit trigger](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus) at the database level that records all changes to an audit table. Beyond that, you could use [log_statemens](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT) in the db configuration to log specific SQL statements, but that's expensive. Another option is to use triggers on the table to update specific columns like `modified_by`

Comment: It's enough to audit the data edit and changes via PgAdmin, this would be the solution for me tho.

https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/working-postgres-audit-triggers